# How to upload a single video on alibaba VOD service

Tags: video-streaming, video-processing, alibaba-cloud

I have been working on Alibaba VOD(Video on Demand) and media processing services from the last couple of months and facing the issue while uploading a video on the console. I had try number of times to upload the video but every time getting the failed.

I don't identify this issue or haven't got any solution yet from anywhere. This is the only concern for posting this question here.

In addition, I and my fellow both had tried to connect with the support team but still haven't received any adequate answer.

I am accessing china based cloud services station from remote India, Is that the cause of facing this issue?

Apart from this, another issue is server downtime, We have noticed that most of the time couldn't able to access the resources over the cloud that's including our own hosted website itself.

Anybody has knowledge or working experience using Alibaba service kindly please let us help.

Overall, my experience using the Alibaba service is not positive.

**update:**
[image]

We got the response from the support team they said that

> According to the screenshot that you provided, the issue is not about
>   accessing the server you built. It is about when visiting our official
>   website, the page cannot be refreshed normally. Since this phenomenon
>   is likely to be caused By the network status. Are you living in China
>   or visiting from oversea network? Can you try to change the network
>   environment to visit and see if it is normal? For example you may try
>   it on diffirent devices and network, such as using mobile to Visit our
>   websites.

Comment: Can your provide more detail? Error message, fixe size, what type of Internet you have, etc. The more details the easier to help.

Comment: I have check the Internet, also try to upload file on different site seems like working fine. It is not related to Internet.

Comment: @JohnHanley Do you have any idea incase we accessing the china offical website in different region cause this issue? Just check this link http://cn.aliyun.com/

Comment: I am uploading a file that size is not more than 1 MB. :)

Comment: Where are you located and what region are connecting to? For the past week or so, I have been working with Alibaba everyday testing their services. I have not had an issue.

Comment: I am from India, Ahmedabad region.

Comment: Which station are you using China or Internation?

Comment: I am not using the China console. All of my testing is the US.

Comment: Okay, One of my other friends also try to use an International console, he did not face any issue yet.

Comment: Do you think chine console may be it's country specific control?

Comment: You can also try to upload using their SDK https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/48467.htm